# Delete columns in a database if the values within the columns are similar

Tags: r, binary

I'm doing a project for school in R and I have a database with many binary values.
I would like to delete specific column.

For exemple if the column "A" only contain the value 1 and NA. The column B only the value 0 and NA. I want to delete this columns. But if the column contain the both (0 and 1) like columns C and D I want to keep them including NA values:

```
    My_data_frame):                   My_future_data_frame):
                    A  B  C  D                                   C  D
                 x  1  0  1  1                                x  1  1
                 y  1  0  0  1                                y  0  1
                 z  1  0  1  0                                z  1  0
                 t  NA NA NA NA                               t  NA NA
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Consider including sample data and the desired output. This will help to motivate people answering your question.

Comment: I put an example :)

Comment: If you have an `NA`, do you have them over the whole row as in your example?

Comment: Thanks you Alex, my problem is resolved. :)

Comment: You could, also, check if the `var`iance in each column is `> 0`; `df[sapply(df, function(x) var(x, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can get rid of constant columns:

```
##### Removing constant columns
cat("\n## Removing the constants columns.\n")
for (f in names(My_data_frame)) {
  if (length(unique(My_data_frame[[f]])) == 1) {
    cat(f, "is constant in my data frame. We delete it.\n")
    My_data_frame[[f]] <- NULL
  }
}
```

And here is the same solution considering the new NA rule I saw :)

```
##### Removing constant columns (considering NA's)
cat("\n## Removing the constants columns .\n")
for (f in names(My_data_frame)) {
  if length(unique(iris[[f]][!is.na(iris[[f]])])) == 1) {
    cat(f, "is constant in my data frame. We delete it.\n")
    My_data_frame[[f]] <- NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: `unique` is a good way to solve this. But your for loop seem at least to me way to complecated for the task at hand. Can you simplify your solution?

Comment: @Alex The other stuff in the loop just making the code document what it's doing, not complicating it, in my opinion.

Comment: I think you can solve it with one short line of code. Compared to that it is complicated. And I would argue that it is for that easy task not necessary.

Comment: well, in my opinion not always less lines of code are better. I've used this way in my work before because it helps me to print out all the constant columns, so I can investigate after about why they are constant (maybe entry error). But of course that will depend on wharever you need to achieve

Comment: Thank you it work perfectly Matias ! :) Thanks for others too ! Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using `colSums`.

```
#Sample Data
X1 <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 30, replace = TRUE, ), ncol = 3)
X2 <- rep(0, 10)
X3 <- rep(1, 10)

data  <- cbind(X1,X2,X3)

> data
            X2 X3
 [1,] 0 1 1  0  1
 [2,] 0 1 0  0  1
 [3,] 1 1 1  0  1
 [4,] 0 0 0  0  1
 [5,] 0 0 1  0  1
 [6,] 1 1 0  0  1
 [7,] 1 1 1  0  1
 [8,] 0 0 1  0  1
 [9,] 0 0 1  0  1
[10,] 1 0 1  0  1
```

Since we have binary data we know that if either the sum equals 0 or equals the number of rows we have zero variance. We can determine the columns for which this is true and then remove them from the data.

```
zero_var_id <- which(colSums(data) == 0 | colSums(data) == nrow(data))
data        <- data[ ,-zero_var_id]
```

Edit: To deal with the `NAs` from the updated example use this:

```
zero_var_id <- which(colSums(na.omit(data)) == 0 | colSums(na.omit(data)) == nrow(na.omit(data)))
data        <- data[ ,-zero_var_id]
```